# how to cancel thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

hey after long research i come up with a way to cancel thread but i face a problem when i cancel thread here is my code first.so for example when i click on button3 while form working its killing the process but it gives me an error (chrome unrechable)

```
public void test1()
{
var dr = new chromdriver();
dr.navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
if(xx != null)
 {
 IWebElement emal = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\"Email\"]"));
 emal.Sendkeys(email)
 }
 else{
  IWebElement emal = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\"Email\"]"));
 emal.Sendkeys(email)
}
}
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   thread thr = new thread(test1);
   thr.Start();}


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        Process[] array = processes;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Process process = array[i];
            process.Kill();
        }
        Thread thr = new Thread(review);
        thr.Abort();
    }
```

Comment: You're not cancelling the thread, you're killing the process. You cannot cancel the chrome thread because it is in another process, so the way you're doing it is about the only way, except that you don't need all that code about threads, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Calling `.Abort()` on a thread can cause the .NET run-time to enter an invalid state and corrupt the execution of all threads - for that reason the only time you should ever call it is when you are trying to forcibly shutdown an app. You should always construct your code so that threads end naturally.

Comment: "[...] i come up with a way to cancel thread but i face a problem when i cancel thread [...]" - Have you found a way or not? What do you actually mean?

Comment: yeah i was declaring variables in wrong location

Answer (score 0):

You variables are declared in wrong location

```
        private Thread thr = null;
        public void test1()
        {
            var dr = new chromdriver();

            dr.navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            if(xx != null)
            {
                IWebElement emal = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\"Email\"]"));
                emal.Sendkeys(email);
            }
            else
            {
                IWebElement emal = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\"Email\"]"));
                emal.Sendkeys(email);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           thr = new Thread(test1);
           thr.Start();
        }


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            Process[] array = processes;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Process process = array[i];
                process.Kill();
            }
            thr.Abort();
        }
```